# Image orientation in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to display an Image in the Application method (not in the controller) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (It's actually a splash screen).
My code

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 640)];

    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashipad.jpg"];
} else {
    //doesn't matter for now
}
```

Actually the image is displayed but it starts not from the up left corner. It's displayed in portrait mode even though the emulator is in landscape mode.

Even if I invert the 1024 with the 640 it want solve the problem.

Wanna to display the splash always in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. The Width & Height might be around the wrong way so just switch them around

```
#define HEIGHT 1024
#define WIDTH 640

( ... )

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH)];
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
    }

    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashipad.jpg"];
} else {
    //doesn't matter for now
}
```

Comment: Nothing changes..I think that the problem is related to the fact that before the loading of the controller the orientation is always portrait.

Comment: so does it always hit the "UIDeviceOrientationPortrait" ? If so try loading the App while the device is in the desired orientation

Comment: yes.but the problem is that in portrait mode the origin 0, 0 starts in another corner. So either it will stretch the image or it will display as in portrait. So need I to load the splashscreen in the didload event of the controller ?

Comment: ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: i believe. I know portrait mode starts with 0,0 in another corner thats why the HEIGHT & WIDTH have switch positions

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the autoresizingMask property of your image view-

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 640)];
    splashView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashipad.jpg"];
} else {
     //doesn't matter for now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or, you can just simply submit the images in the deployment info

i dont know about xcode below 4.2

but if you're using 4.2, you can do this

- go to project navigator > your project
- select target > your project >summary
- below the iPad Deployment info look for "Launch Images" tab, and right click on the "portrait" or "landscape" to choose an image to submit

hope this help ;)